# My programme is goes wrong when i running it

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

```
    assume cs:code
data segment
    db '1975','1976','1977','1978','1979','1980','1981','1982','1983'
    db '1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992'
    db '1993','1994','1995'

    dd 16,22,382,1356,2390,8000,16000,24486,50065,97479,140417,197514
    dd 345980,590827,803530,1183000,1843000,2759000,3753000,4649000,5937000


    dw 3,7,9,13,28,38,130,220,476,778,1001,1442,2258,2793,4037,5635,8226
    dw 11542,14430,15257,17800
data ends

table segment
    db 21 dup ('year summ ne ?? ')
table ends
;First we have to move the data from data segment to table just as the format below
;year(4byte)(20H)income(4byte)(20H)Number of employees(2byte)(20H)per capita income(2byte)(20H)
;Example
;1975  16 3 23

code segment
start:


mov ax,data
mov ds,ax       ;Later we will move data from it

mov ax,table
mov es,ax       ;Later we will move data into it

xor si,si       ;empty the register si
xor bx,bx       ;empty bx
mov cx,21       ;the data is from 1975-1995 so we have to loop for 21 times

s:              ;the purpose of the loop is to move the data(year) from data segment into table segment
mov ax,ds:[bx]
mov es:[si],ax
add bx,2
mov ax,ds:[bx]
mov es:[si+2],ax
add bx,2
add si,10H
loop s

mov cx,21
xor si,si
xor bp,bp
mov bp,5
s1:             ;the purpose of the loop is to move the data(income) from data segment into table segment
mov ax,ds:[bx]
mov es:[si+bp],ax
add bx,2
mov ax,ds:[bx]
mov es:[si+bp+2],ax

add bx,2
add si,10H

loop s1




xor si,si
xor bp,bp
mov bp,0AH
mov cx,21
s2:            ;the purpose of the loop is to move the data(Number of employees) from data segment into table segment
mov ax,ds:[bx]
mov es:[si+bp],ax
add bx,2
add si,10H
loop s2

mov si,000EH
mov bx,168
xor di,di
mov di,84
mov cx,21
s3:         ;the purpose of the loop is to div the data(income/Number of employees) from data segment into table segment

mov ax,ds:[di]
add di,2
mov dx,ds:[di]
div word ptr ds:[bx]
add bx,2
mov es:[bp+13],ax
loop s3

mov ax,4C00H    ;end the programme
int 21H
code ends
end start
```

*when it run to s3 the windows told me the divide if overflow*

**what can i do to solve the bug**

Comment: Why are you doing `mov dx,ds:[di]` prior to `div`? What exactly are you trying to compute?

Comment: Keep in mind that the dividend used by that `div` is the 32-bit value `dx:ax`, and that the quotient must fit in 16 bits.

Comment: I would get a hold of Borland Turbo Debugger 1.x and step through instruction by instruction and set a break point on the `div` which is likely overflowing as @Michael is suggesting. Turbo Debugger can be found on the internet. You can also use Bochs, turn on magic `breakpoint` and then put an `xchg bx, bx` at the beginning of your program. You can then use Bochs to step though the program with its own internal debugger. I recommend turbo debugger to start with.

Comment: I don't know why it's isn't connected from the data (Number of employees)16-22 it's insteaded with 00 for two bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division is correct the first time round, but because you didn't advance the pointer for the dividend by **4** as required, you could get division overflow. This happens because next divisions will be using garbage dividends that will entail a quotient that doesn't fit in the 16 bits of `AX`.

You also forget to initialize and advance the `BP` register for where you store the result.

```
 XOR  BP, BP          <<< initialize BP
 mov  di, 84
 mov  bx, 168
 mov  cx, 21
s3:
 mov  ax, [di]
 mov  dx, [di+2]
 ADD  DI, 4           <<< advance in incomes array (dwords, so plus 4)
 div  word ptr [bx]
 add  bx, 2
 mov  es:[bp+13], ax
 ADD  BP, 16          <<< advance in destination table
 loop s3
```